# Should I use low- or high-level commands for programming classes/packages?

Tags: macros, packages, document-classes

To fix ideas, consider the following example. I can define the command

```
\def\linefill{\kernel@ifnextchar[{\@@linefill}{\@linefill}}
\def\@linefill{\@@linefill[1ex]}
\def\@@linefill[#1]{%
    \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height #1\hfill\kern0pt%
}
```

or I could define it as

```
\newcommand\linefill[1][1ex]{%
    \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height #1\hfill\kern0pt%
}
```

The first form is using low-level commands, while the second form uses higher-level. It is evident that the second is shorter, but I believe there is some overhead associated with using higher-level LaTeX commands.

In this sense, I am wondering the following:

1. Is there any (de facto) standard for classes/packages programming?
2. Is low-level more efficient? Is there any difference in performance at all?
3. Is there any reason to prefer one form over the other?

Thank you very much in advance for your answers!

Comment: your example isn't really a very good example of the general question as the "low level" definition of the command you give is essentially identical to what `\newcommand` will do so there is no run time behaviour difference and the only difference is therefore while loading the package saving half a dozen expansions expanding the definition of  `\newcommand` itself but on modern hardware unless you have several million such definitions in your package you will not be able to measure that.

Comment: also the `\newcommand` version  is robust try using `\tableofcontents \section{a\linefill b}` with both versions

Comment: The thumb's rule my students and I use is to only use `\def` when `\newcommand` is not suitable for the task. It's an option to make it simple to talk with and explain how to use LaTeX to our new non-programmer LaTeX users.

Comment: One other consideration is if you wish the package to operate in plain TeX.  In that case, one must use low level commands and store the package in a filename ending in `.tex`.  In such a case, as with my `tokcycle` package, the `.sty` file is as simple as `\input tokcycle.tex
\ProvidesPackage\tcname[\tcdate\space V\tcver\space Cycle through and transform
  a stream of tokens]
\endinput`.  In Plain TeX, one simply uses `\input tokcycle.tex` rather than `\usepackage{tokcycle}`.